# MySQL Select all rows since the previous occurrence of a certain day of month

Tags: mysql, mariadb

So the idea is simple but i have no idea how to do it and i have not found any useful information online.

I have a system setup to track internet data usage using MariaDB. I have a data cap that resets on the 13th of each month. And i would like to be able to display all data usage for the current cycle.

Is this possible with MySQL? (I will be using grafana to display the data)

Edit: Sorry i did not think to include the table schema

```sql
create table network.data_usage
(
    time     timestamp default current_timestamp() not null on update current_timestamp(),
    mac      varchar(32)                           not null,
    download bigint    default 0                   not null,
    upload   bigint    default 0                   not null
);
```

obviously the time field is the most relevant to this question. the upload and download fields store the total bytes in/out for a specific mac address since the previous entry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you need to compute the appropriate 13th day of the month for the current date. You can get to the 13th day of the current month using

```sql
CURDATE() - INTERVAL DAY(CURDATE()) - 13 DAY
```

Then you just need to subtract a month if the current date is less than 13:

```sql
CURDATE() - INTERVAL DAY(CURDATE()) - 13 DAY - INTERVAL IF(DAY(CURDATE()) < 13, 1, 0) MONTH
```

Having computed that, you can then `SUM` all the `download` and `upload` values since that date:

```sql
SELECT SUM(download) AS downloads,
       SUM(upload) AS uploads,
       SUM(download + upload) AS total
FROM data_usage
WHERE time >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL DAY(CURDATE()) - 13 DAY - INTERVAL IF(DAY(CURDATE()) < 13, 1, 0) MONTH
```

You can also sum for each `mac` value using a `GROUP BY` clause e.g.

```sql
SELECT mac,
       SUM(download) AS downloads,
       SUM(upload) AS uploads,
       SUM(download + upload) AS total
FROM data_usage
WHERE time >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL DAY(CURDATE()) - 13 DAY - INTERVAL IF(DAY(CURDATE()) < 13, 1, 0) MONTH
GROUP BY mac
```

If you are grouping by `mac`, you can also generate a total row by adding `WITH ROLLUP` to the `GROUP BY` clause:

```sql
SELECT COALESCE(mac, 'Total') AS mac,
       SUM(download) AS downloads,
       SUM(upload) AS uploads,
       SUM(download + upload) AS total
FROM data_usage
WHERE time >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL DAY(CURDATE()) - 13 DAY - INTERVAL IF(DAY(CURDATE()) < 13, 1, 0) MONTH
GROUP BY mac WITH ROLLUP
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=3c7bae716213d72a58fca814c8230d7d)

Comment: That seems to be working perfectly. Thank you!

Comment: I do have one related question if you don't mind. Based on what you gave me i figured out a way to calculate the current cycles "progress" by dividing the current day of this cycle by the total number of days in this cycle. It seems to work but i'm just wondering if i have overlooked a simpler alternative.
https://ss.brandon3055.com/a13ed

Comment: @brandon3055 you could simplify the computation of the number of days in the cycle to `day(last_day(curdate() - interval if(day(curdate()) < 13, 1, 0) month))`